How can I discretize the frequency components of a target signal?
I'm trying to perform a time-frequency process in MATLAB to take an audio clip and approximate it with only the center frequencies from each bin created by a constant-Q transform. I have a MATLAB script taking a number of bins-per-octave and creating a new .wav with the inverse-CQT. But this reconstructs the signal perfectly, it seems.
What operation can I perform to discard all but one freq from each bin while still modulating its amplitude appropriately in the time domain? I don't know if that makes any sense. I'm trying to recreate this, basically: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BgeAKc5U2s. I understand the CQT as a sort of STFT with log-spaced frequencies, but I don't have much DSP experience to help me.
